# Scrapy doesn't read the full text within a tag that contains '<' , '>' characters

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

The HTML part looks like this:

```
<p class="header__lede">Affecting
            <strong >
              <a class="breadcrumbs__list-item__link" href="/vuln/rubygems:spree">spree</a></strong> gem, versions <strong ><&nbsp;1.1.2,&nbsp;>=&nbsp;1.1 || <&nbsp;1.0.5,&nbsp;>=&nbsp;0.71 || <&nbsp;0.70.6,&nbsp;>=&nbsp;0.12 || <&nbsp;0.11.4</strong></p>
```

I want to get the texts within this paragraph that are under `strong` tag. My Scrapy output looks like this:

```
In [8]: t = response.xpath(".//p[@class='header__lede']")

In [9]: t.getall()
Out[9]: ['<p class="header__lede">Affecting\n            <strong>\n              <a class="breadcrumbs__list-item__link" href="/vuln/rubygems:spree">spree</a></strong> gem, versions <strong>=\xa01.1 || =\xa00.71 || =\xa00.12 || </strong></p>']

In [10]: t = t.xpath(".//strong/text()")

In [11]: t.getall()
Out[11]: ['\n              ', '=\xa01.1 || =\xa00.71 || =\xa00.12 || ']
```

As you can see, when I was expecting "< 1.1.2, >= 1.1 || < 1.0.5, >= 0.71 || < 0.70.6, >= 0.12 || < 0.11.4" that is displayed on the webpage, Scrapy gives me '=\xa01.1 || =\xa00.71 || =\xa00.12 || ' where some original texts get cut. What is the issue here?

Comment: `<` is interpreted by HTML parsers as an HTML tag start. Use `&lt;` *(less than)* and `&gt;` *(greater than)* to escape those.... Or assign with JavaScript as `.textContent`.

Comment: I am scraping data from a website so the html code is not in my hand. The text shows correctly on that website, it's just that Scrapy fails to identify which is probably because of  confusion with `<` and `>` character. However, in other cases Scrapy can read text with these characters without problem as well. Seems lile `<` with `&nbsp;` creating more confusion. As a one who is scraping the data, what is my option to get around this?

Comment: Try using [$doc = @new DOMDocument;](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead. No guarantees.